# Beginner question about pulley on old Ford Inline six

Tags: ford, pulley

I actually posted this over on the Fordsix.com forum as well but I BELIEVE the question was removed, possibly for being too basic (that or it just hasnt been approved yet because I'm new, not sure).  That said, I can't find it in any shop manual, I've googled, and every youtube video i find about similar pulleys are 40 years more current engines..  So here goes:

So I got a 1961 144 for the low-low price of free about a week ago.  It was lying in the dirt outside and about to be taken to the scrap pile.

Well, I finally got to the first thing that made me think to myself "that doesn't seem right".  Let me explain:

(let me know if those links don't work, I'll figure something else out)

This main pulley (crankshaft right?) seems bent out of place, I thought at first looking at it that it might be warped, but holding a straight edge against it luckily it doesn't seem warped:

[image: 1]

That said, it is smashed right up against the rest of the engine, I can't even slide a piece of paper between it and the engine, that doesn't seem right:

[image: 2]

My gut reaction is to take it off and see what I'm dealing with, which brings me to my next question:  HOW? Is it just the bolt pictured right in the center of it?  Normal lefty-loosey?  I gave it a brief tug but it didn't start loosening and I didn't want to break it. (have torn 3 other bolts already)

[image: 3]

Lastly, I'd imagine that pulley could spin right?  Well it doesn't at all.  The transmission is currently on, that wouldn't prevent it would it?  Does that mean its 'frozen'?  Should I just try to spin it harder?  Am I totally headed the wrong direction?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Remove spark plugs and try looking inside for corrosion. Squirt motor oil into each cylinder. Try turning the engine over manually on the crankshaft and see if it'll turnover. You may have to turn a few degrees in both directions to free up seized piston rings to allow oil lubrication. If you succeed in turning the crankshaft thru at least two full revolutions, crank some more to allow upper cylinder lube. The crank pulley seems in the right place as the mechanical timing bracket is nearby for old school timing light use.